# switch rotation direction depending on var

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

having some trouble with an tweenlite animation in query.
I want to switch the animation direction depending on a variable.
I have a variable that represents "left" or "right". those values is set when the user drags the mouse in that direction. And i need to change my animation so it animates in the right direction depending on this variable. The animation basically flips a div. Like a card flip. Need the get the rotation value somehow dynamic.

Any suggestions?

```
var tb = false;
if (dirX == "right") {
    if (tb == false) {
        TweenLite.to($(this).find(".obj"), 1, {
            rotationY: -180,
            transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
            ease: Back.easeOut,
            onComplete: function () {
                TweenLite.set($(this).find(".obj"), {
                    rotationY: -180
                });
                tb = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if (tb == true) {
        TweenLite.to($(this).find(".obj"), 1, {
            rotationY: -360,
            transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
            ease: Back.easeOut,
            onComplete: function () {
                TweenLite.set($(this).find(".obj"), {
                    rotationY: -360
                });
                tb = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
if (dirX == "left") {
    //the opposit
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fork of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Boolean/b6TUf/4/

Your version did not work for the following reasons.

1. You needed to include the JQueryUI framework.
2. You were not setting `prevXPos = event.pageX;` as I have in my first answer with `prevPos = e.clientX;`. This needs to be done after the direction is set to help keep track of the current direction.
3. You were not instantiating the `dirX` variable.
4. I have targeted ID's rather than classes. It would have worked without but it would not be very optimised.
5. It was spinning many times because you were instantiating the tweens inside the draggable function. This meant that new tweens were being created every times you dragged.
6. You needed to reset the `prevXPos = event.pageX;` on drag start.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! Works fine! What if i want to apply it on a bunch of individual objects instead of just one? say that i for example have 20 divs of that same classname.

Answer (score 0):

A tween can be set relative to a current position using `'+='` or `'-='` syntax.

```
    var prevPos, obj = $('#obj');

    TweenLite.set(obj, {rotationX:30, transformOrigin:"middle middle",transformPerspective:500});

    var tweenLeft =  new TweenLite.to(obj, 1, { rotationY: '+=180', ease: Back.easeOut, paused:true});
    var tweenRight = new TweenLite.to(obj, 1, { rotationY: '-=180', ease: Back.easeOut, paused:true});

    $('#container').mouseenter(function( e ) {
        prevPos = e.clientX;  
    });

    $('#container').mousemove(function( e ) {

        if(!tweenLeft.isActive() && !tweenRight.isActive()){

            if(prevPos > e.clientX){
                tweenRight.restart(); 
            }else if(prevPos < e.clientX){
                tweenLeft.restart();
            }
        }     
        prevPos = e.clientX;

    });
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Boolean/teyHa/5/

Comment: Thank you! I run this on a draggable element. Wich make it an infinite tween. I want it to stop/pause on every 180 so its like: you drag in a direction, it flips, you drag again and it flips  back. How would you do that?

Comment: Now its more of an infinite tween. Do you get me?

Comment: In your 2nd example you removed the line `if(!tweenLeft.isActive() && !tweenRight.isActive())`, which is why it keep repeating. I'll repost code. 
Please accept the answer if it answered your original question.

Comment: Yepp, thats true. And i want it to be slightly different. As you say the tween only runs if not already running. But i also need it to not be infinite as it is now. Cause it runs on a draggable event it gets weird when it starts to tween all the time. So basically i want it only to start once and not be infinite as it is now. I actually pasted the wrong code, will add isActive again.

Comment: Too much guess work. Please could you create your own jsfiddle and I'll fix it.

Comment: Sure, here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/9jHMX/3/
Don't know why the drag event suddenly sopped working on the fiddle tho. Never used fiddle before.

Comment: Ok, i understand. You can actually use your own fiddle that you made. That one works exactly as my local code. With only difference that you do mouseMove and i do Drag. http://jsfiddle.net/Boolean/teyHa/5/